# Key, Value mapping in Object Literals

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I tripped over a javascript question

Initially, response from HTTP was like `[...{67,90},{23,40}]`, Now in order to view this detail in pie chart, i had to convert it into `[{x:67, y: 90}, {x:23, y:40}]`, but now i want this pie data to again look like `[{67,90},{23,40}]`.

For Example:

```
g = [{x: 67, y:90}, {x: 23, y:40}]
```

I tried few things like :
1.

```
Object.keys(pieData).map((item) => {
            return {
                item.x, item.y
            }
        })
```

2.

```
Object.key(Object.entries(g))
```

Required result is:

```
g=[{67,90}, {23,40}]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Second part of the above question is '67', '23' are actually indexes. Can we convert one of the values in index number of the array....?

Comment: result is not a valid JavaScript object.

Comment: Your desired output's syntax is invalid, and there is no such thing as `Object.key`

Comment: Your expected output is wrong. It contains object without keys

Comment: Do you mean you want an array of arrays `[[67,90],[23,40]]`

Comment: See in this way, 67 in above example is a key.

Comment: oh so you mean `[{67:90},{23:40}]`?

Comment: Initially, response from HTTP was like [...{67,90},{23,40}], Now in order to view this detail in pie chart, i had to convert it into [{x:67, y: 90}, {x:23, y:40}], but not i want this pie data to again look like [{67,90},{23,40}]. Is it an illogical question according to you @cer

Comment: Why not just store the original response for future use? Why go back and forth

Comment: @Jamiec its actually not as simple as i wrote, i have a different requirement, but gist is pretty much this. Basically new dataset which after calculation i achieved as piechart data, i need to use it in the form of above result i mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the `x` as the key and the `y` as the value this is what you're looking for.

```js
var g = [{x: 67, y:90}, {x: 23, y:40}];
var result = g.map(item => ({[item.x]:item.y}));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your expected output is wrong because it contains object without `key:value` pairs. You should return array of arrays. Use `map()` and return an array containing both properties.

```js
let g = [{x: 67, y:90}, {x: 23, y:40}]
let res = g.map(({x,y}) => [x,y]);
console.log(res)
```

Comment: Actually i wanted `[{67,90},{23,40}]` but result is `[[67,90],[23,40]]` according to your answer. Also `g.map(({x,y}) => {x,y});` does not work the same way to result `[{67,90},{23,40}]`. However this code snippet have its own benefits in other ways.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the result `g = [{67, 90}, {23, 40}]` that you want is not valid javascript

- I think that what you want is an array of objects `[{67: 90}, {23: 40}]` with the `x` as key and the `y` as value

To get that, as you post in your question you can use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Code:

```js
const g = [{x: 67, y:90}, {x: 23, y:40}];
const result = g.map(o => ({ [o.x]: o.y }));

console.log(result);
```